# NSMutableArray in Singleton. Strong Or Weak Property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I am somewhat lost on how to declare properties in my Singleton. Should I use `strong` or `weak`? Particularly I have an `NSMutableArray` property and I am not sure what to do. Can someone explain in some what detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Singletons, and depends entirely on how your array is being used. Is it private? Public? Readonly? Readwrite? It just depends on ownership, like everything else. If your singleton owns the array, use `strong` or `copy`. Otherwise use `weak`.

That said, it's not typically a good idea to directly expose a mutable collection at all. If you only need other classes to be able to read it, use an `NSMutableArray` internally, and expose an `NSArray` copy publicly. If other classes need to mutate the collection, it's better practice to expose a set of [KVC-compliant methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE) that mutate an internal mutable array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So in this case I want it to be readwrite as it needs to be read and written to during the course of the application. So would it make sense to use (nonatomic, readwrite) or (nonatomic, strong). Sorry. trying to get a hang of it

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between mutating the property and writing to the property. If you really need the property itself to be writable, then yes, use `(nonatomic, strong)` or `(nonatomic, copy)`. The `readwrite` is implicit.